# Increasing rotation via simple gears

Tags: gears

Complete amateur here with a product idea and a need to find out whether it can work in theory.

I need to push a lever vertically down through 90 degrees and have a lateral arm swing horizontally through 180 degrees (and with greater speed than lever one going down).

Is this possible and how should I describe it/specify it for to a prototyping company?

Any advice gratefully received!

PS: Apologies, gentlemen. Here's a sort of diagram.

[image]

Comment: A diagram of the proposed system would help

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Bevel gears provide a simple means of turning rotational motion at right angles. Image source: [What is a bevel gear and how it works](https://medium.com/@dipalibhalekar1810/what-is-bevel-gear-and-how-it-work-ee6eb8c72409).*

In your case you want a 1:2 ratio so your input would be on the large gear and output on small gear.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I wanted the fast gear to move three times as fast, it would be 1:3, and so forth? Can I presume on your good nature for a further calculation? If the second arm - the horizontal arm - was attached to a racket 18 inches long and I wanted to move the tip of the head of that racket at 50mph - what gear ratio would I need to be able to do that, using my own hand/arm to move the first lever?

Comment: That's correct. Don't forget to "accept" if your question has been answered satisfactorily but wait a day or two to encourage other answers which may give you other alternatives.

Comment: This is a good answer, but since the person is asking such a simple question, you might want to provide a bit more detail about implementation. Your picture doesn’t include shafts or bearings necessary to make it work.

Comment: @Eric: Feel free ... You could spend an hour doing a CAD sketch and, without any better specifications from the OP, completely miss the mark.

Comment: I was thinking maybe just finding a different picture such as https://www.123rf.com/photo_106485481_bevel-gear-gear-transmission-rotation-angle-on-white-background-3d-rendering-.html